# JS: Remove all text to the left of certain last character with Regex

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, npm, substring

I'm trying to remove all the text which falls before the last character in a Regex pattern.

Example:

```
rom.com/run/login.php
```

Becomes:

```
login.php
```

How would I go about doing this in JavaScript? I'm new to regular expressions.

Comment: Do you really need to use regular expressions, or is that an assumption you’ve made about what might be ‘easiest’?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get everything after last slash, use `[^\/]+$`

```js
const str = "rom.com/run/login.php";

console.log(str.match(/[^/]+$/)[0]);
```

Comment: Small point: the slash doesn't need to be escaped when it's inside a character class, so `/[^/]+$/` will do.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the result you need by searching for a literal string (just one character in fact) so there's no need to employ regular expressions which will cost you performance.

You can split the input into chunks separated by `/` and get the last chunk:

```
var input = 'rom.com/run/login.php';
var result = input.split('/').pop();
```

Or find the position of the last occurrence of `/` in the input, and get the remainder of the string that follows that position:

```
var input = 'rom.com/run/login.php';
var result = input.substring(input.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with Regex like this:

```js
var url = 'rom.com/run/login.php'
var page = url.match('^.*/(.*)')[1]
console.log(page)
```

Or you could do it without Regex like this:

```js
var url = 'rom.com/run/login.php'
var split = url.split('/')
var page = split[split.length-1]
console.log(page)
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is a regex replacement:

```js
var path = "rom.com/run/login.php";
var output = path.replace(/^.*\//, "");
console.log(output);
```

The regex pattern `^.*/` is *greedy*, and will consume everything up to (and including) the last path separator.  Then, we replace this match with empty string, to effectively remove it.